# How do I scale a UIView designed for iPad, for use with an iPhone?

Tags: ios

I built an iPad game and am now trying to port it to the iPhone. One of my interfaces in the game has buttons that are laid in specific places on top of an image, so I'd like to simply scale what I have built for the iPad down to iPhone size.

Thus far, I have had a little success simply defining my buttons in terms of positions and sizes on the iPad, then simply scaling each button proportionally in code.

```
//
//  ExerciseMenuView.swift
//  Reading Expressway
//
//  Created by Montana Burr on 7/29/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Montana. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

import QuartzCore

@IBDesignable @objc class ExerciseMenuView: UIView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        // Adjust subviews according to device screen size.
        let iPadProWidth = CGFloat(1024);
        let iPadProHeight = CGFloat(768);
        let deviceWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width;
        let deviceHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height;
        for subview in self.subviews {
            let subviewWidthMultiplier = subview.frame.width / iPadProWidth;
            let subviewHeightMultiplier = subview.frame.height / iPadProHeight;
            let subviewCenterXMultiplier = subview.frame.origin.x / iPadProWidth;
            let subviewCenterYMultiplier = subview.frame.origin.y / iPadProHeight;
            let subviewHeight = subviewHeightMultiplier * deviceHeight;
            let subviewWidth = deviceWidth * subviewWidthMultiplier;
            let subviewX = subviewCenterXMultiplier * deviceWidth;
            let subviewY = subviewCenterYMultiplier * deviceHeight;
            subview.frame = CGRect.init(x: subviewX, y: subviewY, width: subviewWidth, height: subviewHeight)
        }
    }
}
```

This is roughly what the screen looks like now, on iPad:

[image: iPad screen]

This is what I want it to look like on an iPhone 8:

[image: Expected iPhone 8 screen]

This is what it actually looks like on an iPhone 8 simulator:

[image: Actual iPhone 8 screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **layoutSubviews**  called 2 or more time so your result very small. 
You can change frame in init method.

OR add flag for check is this first calling

```
var isFirstTime = true 

override func layoutSubviews() {
     super.layoutSubviews()
     if isFirstTime  {
     isFirstTime = false
     // Adjust subviews according to device screen size.
        ...
     }
}
```